# How do I write an RSpec test that confirms Password Reset Token has been Saved to the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm writing a test for my Rails 5 API to confirm a password_reset_token is generated whenever a user requests a password reset.

I have a short password_reset_controller that handles the initial request:

```
class PasswordResetController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].to_s.downcase)
    @user.send_password_reset if @user
  end
end
```

send_password_reset is a method in my user model which calls the the generate_password_reset_instructions:

```
def send_password_reset
  self.generate_password_reset_instructions
  UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
end

def generate_password_reset_instructions
    self.password_reset_token = SecureRandom.hex(10)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.now.utc
    save
end
```

This should save the password_reset_token to my db (indeed, when I debug it, I know it goes through these lines of code). The following test suite passes with the exception of the last one:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Password Reset API' do
    let!(:user) { create(:user) }
  describe 'POST password_reset/new' do

    it 'returns status code 204 with user found' do
      post '/password_reset/new', params: {email: user.email}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(204)
    end

    it 'returns status code 204 with no user found' do
      post '/password_reset/new', params: {email: 'not#anemail.com'}
      expect(response).to have_http_status(204)
    end

    it "sends an email" do
      expect { UserMailer.password_reset(user).deliver }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
    end

    it 'confirmation_email is sent to the right user' do
      UserMailer.password_reset(user).deliver
      mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
      expect(mail.to[0]).to eq user.email
    end

    it 'generates password_reset_token' do
      expect { post '/password_reset/new', params: {email: user.email} }.to change { user.password_reset_token }
    end
  end
end
```

The result I get in the terminal is:

```
Failures:

  1) Password Reset API POST password_reset/new generates password_reset_token
     Failure/Error: expect { post '/password_reset/new', params: {email: user.email} }.to change { user.password_reset_token }
       expected result to have changed, but is still nil
     # ./spec/requests/password_reset_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This seems like it might be caused by the value not saving to the test db, but following suggestions in other posts (Like moving `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'`) to the top of rails_helper.rb does not solve the problem. I know that the actual methods work, as I'm able to get the desired result manually by running the server and making requests, I just can't write a test to confirm that it is indeed working. As the syntax in my test would indicate, I'm using FactoryGirl in my tests to generate users.

Any ideas as to why the last test (`it 'generates password_reset_token' do`) does not pass?

Comment: I recommend only using `save` when you don't care if the record gets saved or if you're handling `save` returning false, as is often the case in controllers where you'll redirect the user with a flash message. Use `save!` if you want errors to bubble up. I'd guess something is preventing the record from being saved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but changing to `save!` did not cause any errors to bubble up. As I mentioned, the method itself works, and saves if I make the calls manually, I just can't replicate this behavior in a test.

Comment: I'd recommend returning an error if the user isn't found. Right now that's another area where your app can fail silently. Granted the way your tests are setup the user will exist, but if it didn't and a nil or invalid email got sent into the action, you wouldn't know and you'd be chasing down errors in the wrong place. I'm just trying to eliminate variables here.

Comment: Is the log showing an update for users table?

Comment: There's an if statement in the password_reset_controller which checks if the users is in the db first before calling the send_password_reset method. When I call the method manually, there is an update to the users table. When I debug during the test, I can confirm that a user is found for the test case I'm running. All good suggestions though, I appreciate the checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RSpec.describe 'Password Reset API' do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
  ....

  it 'generates password_reset_token' do
    expect { post '/password_reset/new', params: {email: user.email} }.to change { user.password_reset_token }
  end
end
```

What you expect:

- You're creating a User and expecting it to be changed.

What is happening:

- You create a Ruby User object in your test
- You expect that object to be changed
- Your Rails code initializes a new User object which updates the database and changes the attribute
- Your test object remains untouched

What you need to do is to `reload` your test object with fresh attribute values from the database using `user.reload.password_reset_token`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the reload syntax would look like?

Comment: `user.reload.password_reset_token`

Comment: Awesome, that did it, thank you! Do you want to update your answer so I can accept it?